# lowercasing & converting files to text an empty *.txt file appeared

Tags: bash

I check if there's some files of a certain kind inside a folder to lowercase the extension and then extract the content this way:

```
existDoc=""$(ls | grep .DOC | wc -l)

if [ $existDoc -gt 0 ]; then
    for file in *.DOC
    do
        mv $file $(basename "$file" .DOC)".doc"
    done
fi
```

and then conversion

```
for word in *.doc
    do
        text_doc=""$(basename "$word" .doc)
        sudo catdoc $word > $text_doc".txt"
    done
```

The issue is that a new empty file is created named "*.doc.txt" with no apparent reason.

Comment: you used $text_doc and $textdoc in your question. is this a typo?

Comment: Use `set -x` to see what is going on.

Comment: You can rename the files with `rename "s/.DOC$/.doc/" *`. Use `rename -n "s/.DOC$/.doc/" *` to check the result before.

Comment: you could simplify your "for file in *.DOC" segment by just removing the "if" from the outside -- if there are no *.DOC files, the loop won't execute anything. Just like your second segment does with *.doc files.

Comment: since you've tagged bash, see also: `mv "$file" "${file,,}"`

Comment: ikkachu , sometimes "*.doc" sometimes, "*.doc.txt" , so both appeared depending on the original files

Comment: Can't use "rename" Marco because when I tried it the docX files were renamed to doc and catdoc crashed with docX files . Maybe my fault. Will try with your code snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things:

- [Do not parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).
- [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).
- `sudo`? Why?

If I understand you correctly, you would like to lowercase the extension of all `*.DOC` filenames and use `catdoc` to create text files of them.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for doc in ./*.DOC; do
    new_doc="${doc%.DOC}.doc"
    txt_doc="${doc%.DOC}.txt"

    catdoc "$doc" >"$txt_doc"
    mv "$doc" "$new_doc"
done
```

Or even shorter:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for doc in ./*.DOC; do
    catdoc "$doc" >"${doc%.DOC}.txt"
    mv "$doc" "${doc%.DOC}.doc"
done
```

- The `${doc%.DOC}` is using the `${parameter%word}` parameter expansion of `bash` (or any POSIX shell) to remove the `.DOC` suffix from the filename in `$doc`.
- Setting the `nullglob` shell option will ensure that nothing is matched by `*.DOC` if there are no files with the `.DOC` suffix. If not set, I would get the string `*.DOC` in `$doc` if there were no `.DOC` files.
- Use a `./` prefix in `./*.DOC` to avoid problems with filenames starting with `-`.

Comment: sudo is used because the destination folder is owned by root. Otherwise the files would not be written  Kusalananda

Comment: @jomaweb In that case you either need `sudo` for the `mv` as well, or to run the whole thing with `sudo` in a script.  I would personally do all the processing first, and then move the files in place with `sudo mv`.

Comment: using for doc in *.DOC gives me an error when no DOC file is present

Comment: @jomaweb This is probably because you did not set `shopt -s nullglob`?